# ServiceNotFoundException but id exists

Tags: php, symfony

After uploading a revision to a sandbox site on a shared host I get `...You have requested a non-existent service "ps_pdf.facade"... in bootstrap.php.cache...` when generating a PDF for download with `psliwa/PdfBundle`.  The error does not appear in either dev or prod mode on local Windows system.

Possibly relevant:

- `composer.json` uploaded to host, `composer update` run without error
- `.../src` directory removed and replaced via ftp
- `AppKernel.php`, revised config elements uploaded.
- `$ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug` run without error.
- composer shows `psliwa/php-pdf`
- remove & reinstall of `psliwa/pdf-bundle:~1.0` makes no difference

Site otherwise appears to behave as expected.

Edit #2:

I now know that the text 'ps_pdf.facade' appears in the dev system's `.../app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php` but not in the host's.  Next up: what determines the contents of `appProdProjectContainer.php`?

Edit:  Output of console command:

```
% php app/console debug:container ps_pdf.facade

Information for Service "ps_pdf.facade"
=======================================

 ------------------ -----------------------
  Option             Value
 ------------------ -----------------------
  Service ID         ps_pdf.facade
  Class              PHPPdf\Core\Facade
  Tags               -
  Scope              container
  Public             yes
  Synthetic          no
  Lazy               no
  Synchronized       no
  Abstract           no
  Autowired          no
  Autowiring Types   -
  Factory Service    ps_pdf.facade_builder
  Factory Method     build
 ------------------ -----------------------
```

Comment: `composer install` ?

Comment: It was an update to a previous installation (`.../vendor` exists and is populated with virtually all bundles, just previous versions)  so `composer update` was more appropriate than `composer install`.

Comment: A `composer update` on a remote server is a terrible idea. You should set your dependencies in your `composer.json` and `compose install` from there. Have you rebooted the server/PHP provider (cleared the OpCache)?

Comment: Please explain why a `composer update` of an existing, albeit remote, application is a bad idea.  What advantage does `composer install` provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ta da!  I deleted the existing prod cache and used 'cache:warmup -e=prod`.  It now works.